# In Vim, how to enable Meta in all keybindings?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, iterm2

In case it's relevant, this is on MacOS and iTerm.

How do I use key mappings that involve the Meta key, e.g. `<M-e>`?

For example, the [auto-pairs plugin](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) has a keybinding that allows you to convert `(|)foo` to `(foo)` by pressing `<M-e>`, where `|` represents cursor position.

In `iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > Keys`, I have the following options selected:

[image]

So whenever I pressed `<M-e>`, the behavior becomes `<Esc>e`.  Note that changing the options to `Normal` or `Meta` in iTerm did not fix this issue.

In the end, I was only able to get this plugin command to work by adding the following to my `.vimrc`: `set <M-e>=^[e`, where `^[` is the escape literal achieved by pressing `Ctrl-v` followed by `Esc`.

In general, this is far from an ideal solution, since I'd having to manually set every single mapping involving Meta.

So my question is: **how can I get all keybindings involving the Meta key to perform as expected**, without needing to manually remap each individual instance?

Comment: Meta behavior is not ideal in case you are using vim in terminal. Terminal emulators handle meta keys two ways, mostly using `<Esc>`. So, if you are using vim in a terminal emulator that is not supporting meta by default, you should not use meta. Otherwise you can adopt something that tpope did in [vim-rsi](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi/blob/master/plugin/rsi.vim#L68-L94) plugin.